# send the main parameter to a function in shell script

Tags: shell

I write a script under UNIX System which receives a set of parameters and the number of parameters is not fixed.

The number of parameters depends on the value of the 1st and 2nd parameters (**$1, and $2**)

In this shell script, I write a function. How can I pass the rest of parameters to this function?

Comment: Are you trying to pass *every* argument to the function or every argument *after* the first two?

Comment: but the number of arguments is unknown

Comment: That doesn't matter ultimately. Can you just answer my question?

Comment: how to pass them? like :   myfunction $@      ?? Ah, yes, I will start using from $3

Comment: you can use the command `shift` to remove the arguments you already got, and then `$@` will store the rest of the arguments.

Comment: how to use shift to remove the arguments? Can you be clearer? Or write it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this sort of thing.

The most common way you will see is to simply `shift` off the arguments you have processed after you have processed them.

```
#!/bin/sh

arg1=$1
arg2=$2
shift 2

myfunction "$@"
```

A less common (but very useful and worth knowing) alternative is to use array range expansion (called `Substring Expansion` in [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for its string usage) to select just the array/positional arguments you want.

```
#!/bin/sh

arg1=$1
arg2=$2

myfunction "${@:3}"
```